# What's the most common way to join photos with geographic data?

Tags: photos, geotag

Increasingly spatial data will contain a column that has URL's pointing to images hosted on Flickr, Dropbox or some other cloud based storage system.

What's the most common/efficient way to join photos with geographic data? Are there any fast ways to do it in bulk, or do most people just enter them manually?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "joining", or some example you have in mind?

Comment: As in add a column to the data called "images" which contains url's that point to photos in the cloud.

Comment: What's the cardinality? One to one, one to many, etc? Also, what properties of the photo relate them to the geographic data, if any? Are they geotagged?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use FME to do stuff like this (but then - disclaimer - I do work for the company that creates it). The Data Interop extension in ArcGIS will also do this for you if you don't have the full FME.

So... there is a great example of reading photos and making them into Geodatabase attachments on our knowledgebase, [FMEpedia](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Example-using-FME-to-load-images-into-Geodatabase-attachments).

Basically you need some form of ID to match the image to the feature (presumably the value of an attribute in the data). Then you can read a list of image files with the PATH format reader, like so:

[image]

...merge the data together (with the FeatureMerger) and simply write out the full filename using the attribute path_windows (or unix, or whatever).

The alternative method is to actually read the files, convert the raster data to a blob field, and write that to your output (i.e. instead of a link to the image, you store the image as a blob)

[image]

If the images are geotagged, then you could instead use a SpatialRelator transformer to be able to match them to the spatial feature using a spatial predicate like "INSIDE" or "WITHIN". You could use either of the above techniques (write a link, or write a blob field) in this way.

But I think that - whatever software you use - you must have *some* form of attribute or spatial relationship in order to be able to automatically match the photo to the feature. If not, then I think you are stuck with a manual process.

Answer (score 1):

I did a project for a trip to Peru where I went through the photos I had and linked them to points in ArcGIS. I created a feature in the database that appeared as points, but had a Raster field, so I would create the point feature and then the raster column had a drop-down menu I believe, where I could attach the related picture. Not sure if it's the best way or not, but was the only thing I found that worked at the time and was fairly simple to do. If I remember correctly the photos had to be located on your system, vs web, but I could be wrong, so might be worth checking out at least.

Answer (score 0):

if your getting the images from a generic webpage such as wikipedia you can build a sql string in an attribute table such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/[NAME].

[NAME] being the name of your geographic feature.

You can also use the BLOB data type to store images.